# Wilcoxon test in R - x must be numeric error

Tags: r

I have a problem with the `wilcox.test` in R. 
My data object is a matrix in which the first column contains a name, and all other columns contain a (gene expression) measurement, which is numeric:

```
str(myMatrix)
'data.frame':   2000 obs. of  143 variables:
$ precursor               : chr  "name1" "name2" "name3" "name4" ...
$ sample1: num  1.46e-03 2.64e+02 1.46e-03 1.46e-03 1.46e-03 ...
$ sample2: num  1.46e-03 1.91e+02 1.46e-03 1.46e-03 1.46e-03 ...
$ sample3: num  1.46e-03 3.01e+02 1.46e-03 1.46e-03 4.96 ...
```

For all of the 2000 rows I want to test whether there is a difference between 2 given parts of the matrix. I tried this in 4 different ways:

```
wilcox.test(as.numeric(myMatrix[i,2:87],myMatrix[i,88:98]))$p.value
#[1] 1.549484e-16

wilcox.test(myMatrix[i,2:87],myMatrix[i,88:98])$p.value
#Error in wilcox.test.default(myMatrix[i, 2:87], myMatrix[i, 88:98]) : 
#'x' must be numeric

t.test(as.numeric(myMatrix[i,2:87],myMatrix[i,88:98]))$p.value
#[1] 0.2973957

t.test(myMatrix[i,2:87],myMatrix[i,88:98])$p.value
#[1] 0.3098505
```

So as you can see, only if I use `as.numeric()` on the already numeric values I get a result without an error message for the Wilcoxon test, but the results completely differ from `t.test` results even if they should not.

Manually verifying by using an online tool shows that the `t.test` results using `as.numeric()` values are wrong.

Any suggestions about how I can solve this problem and do the correct Wilcoxon test? If you need more information let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting the error in the code without `as.numeric`, but `as.numeric(myMatrix[i,2:87], myMatrix[i,88:98])` ignores the second argument and returns the same result as `as.numeric(myMatrix[i,2:87])`. It looks like you actually want `as.numeric(myMatrix[i,2:87]), as.numeric(myMatrix[i,88:98])`.

Comment: Could you run this:
`colnames(myMatrix)[which(unlist(lapply(1:dim(myMatrix)[2],function(x)class(myMatrix[[x]])))!="numeric")]`
To check that all cols are numeric.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When using as.numeric() for both arguments, it seems to work! Running your line Nightwriter returns all column names, even if the values inside are shown numeric (see my first code example above)

Comment: It's a confusing error, but it looks like the problem is that myMatrix [i, 2:87], etc is a data frame, which wilcox.test doesn't know how to deal with. Using `unlist` or `as.matrix` has the same effect here as using `as.numeric`, and either one would make it easier to tell what it's actually there for. Alternatively, you could keep your data in a true matrix, which would mean you'd need to get rid of the "precursor" column (you can keep that info around as row names).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, myMatrix [i, 2:87] is still a data.frame. See the following example.

```
> myMat  
    fir X1 X2 X3 X4  
1 name1  1  5  9 13  
2 name2  2  6 10 14  
3 name3  3  7 11 15  
4 name4  4  8 12 16  
> class(myMat[1, 2:4])  
[1] "data.frame"  
> as.numeric(myMat[1, 2:4])  
[1] 1 5 9
```

Change your data to a real Matrix will solve your problem.

```
> myMat_01 <- myMat[, 2:5]  
> rownames(myMat_01) <- myMat$fir  
> myMat_01 <- as.matrix(myMat_01)  
> class(myMat_01[1, 2:4])  
[1] "integer"
```